# TimeOut for EJB method calls

Tags: jakarta-ee, timer, timeout, ejb

Hy,
is there a way i can force an EJB method to stop processing  and return control to the caller with an exception?

In my application i have many call to remote ejb, something like this:

```
@Stateless      
public class ClassSB implements ClassLocalISB {

@Override
public List<Object> businessMethod(String value) {
        long start = 0;
        try {
            //CALL TO EJB
            retVal = ejb.search(value);

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
 }
}
```

Now, for performance issue, i need to stop the execution of

> ejb.search(value)

if it takes too long, in this case i would throw an application exception to the caller.
I know that the `TimerService` interface allow to create a timer, but I can not throw exception exactly with the timeout and, on top of that, it seems that the EJB method continue to processing.

Comment: Which server are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glassfish as well as Weblogic and probably other containers has this feature:

> To implement a synchronous RMI timeout, use the remote-client-timeout
>   deployment descriptor element found in the weblogic-ejb-jar.xml

But be sure to read [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs100/rmi/rmi_api.html#wp1000014372) and Guidelines on Using the RMI Timeout.

Comment: thanksss...i will prove...but what about if i use a @TransactionTimeoutSeconds instead?

Comment: A viable solution, but I believe that every line of code/config has to have exact meaning, so it would probably depend on what your intentions are - do you want to manage transaction in specific way or manage remote EJB invocation. Unless you're not a big fan of deployment descriptors, but I'm not a big fan of mixing configuration and logic;]